# Javascript scope : why foo returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I tried this snippet in fiddle, it returns undefined but according to this book https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch1.md it should return 4 so what's the matter ?

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log( a + b );
}

var b = 2;

document.write(foo( 2 )); // undefined instead of 4
```

Comment: use `return` instead of `console.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at your code>

You have a function foo that is current just displaying the sum of a and b. 
It isn't 1. storing it anywhere 
2. Returning it . Functions need to be called to perform certain tasks and return something.

`console.log()` only displays it on the console rather than returning it to whatever called the function.

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log( a + b );
}
```

What you should do either calculate the mathematics whats done in foo(), or store it in a variable and return it.

```
function foo(a){
    c = a + b;
    console.log(c); //If you want to display it in the console in the first place.
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [MDN page for return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this
>   function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the
>   function caller. **If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned
>   instead.**

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not returning a value, instead your should do this:

```
function foo(a) {
    return a + b;
}

var b = 2;

document.write(foo( 2 ));
```

Or just execute `foo(2);` and check your console for the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

You do a `console.log` in the function foo which does not return anything. You should `return a + b`.